# How to generate all possible 4 letter words in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to write a program that can give me all 4 letter words (from the dictionary or outside the dictionary). I code in C++. And by far, I've reached nowhere.
I'm simply a beginner in C++, I can apply the logic but I'm not introduced to advanced features in C++. It doesn't matter if it takes a long time for this program to end execution, I just want the solution.

For example:

```
abcd
king
ngik
cbda
play
lpay
payl
```

and so on (just a few of the millions of outputs I hope this program to output).

NOTE: The words generated need not make sense and I do not want to discard any combinations, I want it all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is disfavoured by the community to ask for a solution without showing what you have tried yourself so far. Please edit your post and show some code of your own and describe what difficulties you're having with it.

Comment: Two hints: Four nested `for` loops, and the first string will be `"aaaa"` and the last `"zzzz"`.

Comment: So far I've reached nowhere....I need some fast help..

Comment: Can you tell us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? If you understand the logic, then at least you could provide the pseudo code that you can't manage to convert to real C++ code, and tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg can you please elaborate?

Comment: Btw, there won't be millions of words in the output. There will be 456976, assuming a 26-character alphabet.

Comment: Nope, instead I encourage you to experiment! You *do* know that character literals can be used as normal integers? Like for example you can do comparison and arithmetic on them like `char c = 'a'; if (c < 'z') { c++ }` etc.

Comment: "So far I've reached nowhere....I need some fast help...": this is about the worse comment you can say. Not only does it mean that you made no real effort, but also you want others to do it for you, and QUICK !

Comment: @BartvanNierop lovely link

Comment: Also remember that all strings in C are actually one character longer than reported by e.g. `strlen`. This is because for functions to know when and where strings ends, they have a special terminator character: `'\0'`. This means that a four-character string really needs to be five characters long, where the last character is the terminator.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I actually did it. Just for fun. ideone doesn't like 456976 lines of output.

Comment: If you were asked to print out "all possible letters from the alphabet", what would you do? Would your first thought be to randomly pick letters or would there be a better approach that guaranteed you'd printed all of them?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Why talk about `strlen` and the length issues with C strings, when it's a C++ question? `std::string::size()` has no such problem.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest looping say `i` from 0 to 26^4 - 1, each time outputting 'A' + i / (26*26*26), 'A' + i / (26*26) % 26, 'A' + i / 26 % 26, and 'A' + i % 26, then a newline.

Comment: very wise approach, I would accept and learn from you if I were OP

Comment: Technically there's no guarantee that `'B' - 'A' == 1`. The formal approach is to use `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[i]`.

Comment: @MSalters: agreed - no guarantee from the C++ Standard, but after 35 years programming I'm still to work on a system where the implementation doesn't itself guarantee that.

Comment: @TonyD: Last time for me was 10 years ago, but chances are that that system is still running.

Comment: @MSalters yikes - did/does it have a C++ compiler...?

Comment: @TonyD: I'm fairly certain it now has a C++11 compiler, even. But happily we standardized on Unicode :D

Answer (score 2):

Make a array that has all the possible letters in it(add numbers and symbols if you want).
Then use four nested `for` loops that loop a number from 0 to the length of the array.

Lets say that the loop number variables are a,b,c,d.

In the inner loop(the last one) you can output it as array[a] + array[b] + array[c] + array[d]

This gives all the possible combinations where you can add numbers and symbols aswell.

Comment: Just to make things clear, if I need a 10 letter word,i would need how many for loops?

Comment: @blackMaster 10, but you should probably think about recursion. Also, generating _all_ words with 10 characters would take a while. Assuming you could generate a billion words per second, that would be about 3 hours. But that's being extremely optimistic.

Comment: Then you would need 10 for loops, this will require some time for your program to run.

Comment: I don't want to change my code everytime I want a word of different length to be given as output...

Comment: @blackMaster may I ask what you want with this type of code for?

Comment: @blackMaster Hence, recursion.

Comment: @Life of Madness , for purposes involving curiosity

Comment: @blackMaster using to much (nested)for loops is not recommended as it will take a long time to do these loops, for a 4 letter combo. this is possible. If you want anymore i would suggest finding some other solution.

Comment: @LifeofMadness: No better solution exists. Those nested for loops will be just as fast as any other approach, if not faster. The main problem is actually going to be what you **do** with these results. Even an SSD can't keep up with the speed with which you'd produce them. Not too mention, it won't be large enough. You'd need a few **million**.

Answer (score 1):

use recursion

explore DFS a 26-ary tree and output the letter every time you go down on the corresponding branch. depth = 4.

P.S. recursive algorithms eat stack memory like hell... so be sure your machine let programs have enough stack mem. You don't wanna run this on a pic micro with only 3-level call stack :-)

Comment: That would be my solution, too.

Comment: It's only four calls deep, memory really shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: of course. I just wanted to point out that recursive algorithms can use much more stack memory than iterative ones

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Nice idea! But how can we quickly generate the adjacency lists for every node?